# RSpec: How to get the number of tests excluded by `c.filter_run_excluding`?

Tags: ruby, rspec, filter-run-excluding

RSpec has this nice method to exclude individual tests/examples or whole groups by using `filter_run_excluding` in the config, then tagging the examples:

- http://rspec.info/documentation/3.7/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration.html#filter_run_excluding-instance_method
- https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-7/docs/filtering/exclusion-filters

Example:

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.filter_run_excluding :xcode => true
end

RSpec.describe "something" do
  it "does one thing" do
  end

  it "does another thing that needs xcode", :xcode => true do
  end
end
```

"does one thing" will be checked,
"does another thing" will not.

---

We are using this for example to skip some tests depending on the platform the test is run on by wrapping the `c.filter_run_excluding :skip => true` in an `if` block:

```
If Mac, 
   no exclusions, 
if Ubuntu, 
   exclude tests that do something with Xcode.
```

---

Right now the numbers of passing examples/tests is just lower if the exclusion filter is used, but it would be nice to see the actual number of tests that are skipped.

Is there a way to get the number of tests skipped by this method during a test run?

Comment: Also discussed here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rspec/5qeKQr_7G7k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, based on the discussion I had with Myron Marston at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rspec/5qeKQr_7G7k:

RSpec does not provide a way to get the number of examples that are not run because of exclusion filters. But it provides a way to "skip" examples, which also marks the tests as "pending":

> 500 examples, 0 failures, 20 pending

You tag the examples as before, then add:

```
# spec_helper.rb
require 'rbconfig'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  unless RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'] =~ /darwin/
    config.define_derived_metadata(:xcode) do |meta|
      meta[:skip] = "Can only be run on OS X"
    end
  end
end
```

This will add `:skip` to all examples that are tagged with `:xcode` when run on a system that is not macOS.

A special case are examples that trigger a `before(:all)` hook:

If your tags are only active under special conditions (e.g. when the tests are run on a specific platform), you can manually "skip" out of execution of the hook by checking the same condition:

```
before(:all) do
  skip "reason to skip" if should_skip?
  # rest of your hook logic
end
```

Alternatively, you can override the hook globally and access the metadata created by tagging again:

```
module HookOverrides   
  def before(*args)
    super unless metadata[:skip]   
  end 
end

RSpec.configure do |c|   
  c.extend HookOverrides 
end
```

Constraint here: You have to tag the parent element (most probably a example group via `describe`) of the hook, only then the metadata will be available in the hook. You can't just tag the individual examples (as they are "behind" the hook) and excluding individual examples to not be skipped by setting `skip: false` will also not work.

And that's it. Read the whole mail thread at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rspec/5qeKQr_7G7k for details.

Thanks to Myron for taking the time to help me with that, I very much appreciate it.